# Facebook - send simple 'share story' from the website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i need to create specific Facebook Share story. User clicks the button, and lets say, X amd Y send to Facebook and publishes at his timeline like:

**'/username/ achieved X and Y results at chaoschallenge.org'**

I know that I should use Open Graph API for that. I already have Like and Share buttons on the site, but I failed to found a good tutorial how to make additional sharing with data send from my site.

Sorry if there was such a question already.

Comment: I have a guide on how to implement achievements in Unity in my blog. If that is what you are looking for, you can just take out the unity part and keep the Graph API calls to do this in the platform you are looking for.

http://blog.bigfootgaming.net

Comment: @GastonClaret Thanks, I'll study that. I wish I had en example of data sending from a website to the timeline.

Comment: Like I said, should be pretty similar. The Graph calls don't change. Glad it helped